# Placing image in front of background

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a section that slides in to view with a blue background. I'm trying to put a picture in the upper left corner, but It's barely visible and the blue background disappears.

part of HTML:

```
<header id="main">
    <a href="#" id="stackoverflow" class="icons"></a>
</header>
<section id="stack" class="news"></section>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#stackoverflow').click(function(){
    $('#stack').toggle('slow', $st);
    $('#stack').css({'background': 'url(stack.jpeg) no-repeat', 'position':'absolute', 'z-index':'1'});
});
```

CSS:

```
#stack{
float: left;
}

.news{ 
position: absolute;
z-index: -1; 
width: 600px;
background-color: #0000FF;
padding: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
box-shadow: 3px 2px 3px #000;
}

.news a{
position: absolute;
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
}

.news a:hover{
color: #dc692e;
}

.news td{
padding: 5px 10px;
border-bottom: 2px #fff solid;
}
```

Here is what it looks like without me trying ti put an image in the corner:[image]

Here's a picture when I try to add a image in the corner: [image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why the blue back ground is disappearing is due to your overwriting the actual background. You should be able to get what your after with this:

```
$('#stackoverflow').click(function(){
    $('#stack').toggle('slow', $st);
    $('#stack').css({'background': 'url(stack.jpeg) no-repeat BLUE', 'position':'absolute', 'z-index':'1'});
});
```

Also to add, since your placing the image as a background here I would suggest adding some padding to the top of said element to make it that the text doesn't over lay your image.

A better solution to this would be to actually inject said image into the particular element. IE:

```
$('#stack').prepend('<img id="theImg" src="theImg.jpg" />')
```

Comment: +1 `background` overwrites `background-color` or `background-image`

Comment: +1 indeed. That was it. I was one word away from the solution. Oh well. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @Nilzone- not a problem, make sure to check out the revisions I made. It could possibly provide a new outlook on how your trying to accomplish this!

Comment: I just saw it actually. Gonna give it a try! Thank you.